# Azure OS Disk naming convention

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

My Azure VM's OS disk's URI is as below:
https://foxservice.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/Fox-APP-Service-0220170206160459.vhd

I have read in few blogs that the naming convention of the VHD "Fox-APP-Service-0220170206160459.vhd" has a "created date" embedded to it. Does anyone know what the number "0220170206160459" stands for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fox-APP-Service-0220170206160459.vhd,  Does anyone know what the number "0220170206160459" stands for?

Fox-APP-Service-0220170206160459.vhd

`Fox-APP-Service-02` stand for VM name,  `20170206160459` stand for created time.

For example, the VM name is `jas`, `jasonvm` and `Fox-APP-Service-02`, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Andres is correct. The formatting correlates to the time the VHD was created.

It works like so:

Year
Month
Day
Time (in UTC)

So 20170206160459 means the VHD was created 
Year: 2017
Month: 02
Day: 06
Time 16:04:59 UTC

Answer (score 1):

I could take a guess and say that "20170206160459" corresponds to February 6, 2017 at 4:04:59 pm. I'm just not sure about the "02" at the beginning.